# import image file into MATLAB from RADAN software (.dzt file)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, import, file-import

I have a RADAN software (.DZT format) grey scale image file (GPR Profile), which I would like to directly import into MATLAB. Kindly need help with regards to that. 
The DZT file format can be found in the back of the SIR-3000 manual (for 16 bit data)  Addendum A and B,(page 55- 57). Thank you so much for taking time to review my question and answering it. Really it is much appreciated!
LINK: https://support.geophysical.com/gssiSupport/Products/Documents/Control%20Unit%20Manuals/GSSI%20-%20SIR-3000%20Operation%20Manual.pdf

Comment: This appears to be a highly specialized proprietary format, however the developers appear to [provide several conversion utilities](http://www.geophysical.com/softwareutilities.htm) (Windows only). Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Hi @horchler thank you so much for your reply and link.. No i did not knew about this..thanks for enlightening me.. I will download and convert the dzt file into bitmaps and/or ASCII text and then import into MATLAB .. converting from bitmap or ASCII into MATLAB would be much easier I believe?